# Variable transforms in snippets using tabstop number

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the tabstop integers as variables for transforms. In sublime transforms allow for the following behavior:

```
This is a ${1:simple} snippet

This snippet is ${1/complex/not/} for beginners
```

Expected behavior would be that anything but `complex` prints `This snippet is  for beginners` (when `complex` is entered is should print `This snippet is not for beginners`)

I tried in my custom version of Monaco and haven't managed to get it working but I've noticed that the documentation doesn't explicitly names this as a feature.

Has anyone managed to get this working? If so I'll update this question with more specifics about my setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholder tranformations aren't supported yet, only variable (eg `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/match/replacement/}`. The issue in the Visual Studio Code repo that tracks this is here:

[Snippet transformations for placeholders #34683](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34683)